# Definition for rule 'node/no-missing-import' was not found node/no-missing-import

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

folks.

I am running into a bunch of these error whenever I start View. the app isn't render at all.

```
src/App.js
  Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'node/no-missing-import' was not found  node/no-missing-import

src/index.js
  Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'node/no-missing-import' was not found  node/no-missing-import

src/reportWebVitals.js
  Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'node/no-missing-import' was not found  node/no-missing-import

src/util/index.js
  Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'node/no-missing-import' was not found  node/no-missing-import

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: These look like eslint warnings, not errors, and they should not prevent your app from starting.

Comment: So, did you install the definitions for all rules that you are using?

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to you. I really appreciate your time and patience. I have install all dependencies with npm install, and the eslint shows as dev dependence. am I missing any step?